# Reducing solutions from Solve to positive solutions

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

Consider the following lines;

```
Clear[r, R, H, s]
rel1 = 2 r == 1/2 H;
rel2 = r/R == (H - r)/s;
rel3 = H^2 + R^2 == s^2;
solH = Solve[rel1, H][[1]]
sols = Solve[rel2 /. solH, s][[1]]
solR = Solve[rel3 /. solH /. sols, R, PositiveReals][[1]]

Quote = (\[Pi] R s + \[Pi] R^2)/(4 \[Pi] r^2) /. sols /. solR [[1]]
```

1. For the `solR` line I added `PositiveReals` to avoid two solutions where I manually had to use `[[2]]` to specify the correct solution. However, clearly, and logically, Mathematica does not know if $r>0$. How can I state/define that, perhaps as a ‘preface,’ after `Clear`, before calculations starts?
2. Is it necessary to use `[[1]]` for `solH` and `sols` (and for `solR`)? I got an error when removing them from `solH` and `sols` when `solR` is calculated. Is there a better way to write these two lines without using `[[1]]`?

Any other comments and recommendations to improve the code are most welcome.

TIA

Comment: From the documentation, "Solve[expr, vars] attempts to solve the system expr of equations or inequalities for the variables vars." Constraints such as `r > 0` can be included in the **system** `expr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the solution and give r > 0 as an assumption:

```
solR = Simplify[Solve[rel3 /. solH /. sols, R, PositiveReals][[1]], Assumptions -> {r > 0}]
```

I doubt there is a better way to access the solution than `[[1]]` as Solve always returns a list, of which you are interested in the first element.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to define, e.g. r>0, at the beginning of a note book and then let Mathematica remember that in future calculations without Assumptions?

Comment: yes, you can set the assumptions as `$Assumptions = { r > 0 }` - but you still need the `Simplify` around the `Solve`

Comment: That is great. Many thanks!